# SQL Adding several rows and substracting from three tables with date constrains Completely Stuck

Tags: sql-server, join, addition

I am trying to extract sums from two different tables subtracting them and joining them to a first one. The first has customers, the second sales by month and the third returns. I can make it work if I join any of the last two with the first one, but when trying to put the whole thing together I just get crazy nums. Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

First query, works ok:

```
SELECT  
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME,
    SUM (CASE 
            WHEN (INVI.DTTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) -1, -1))
               THEN INVI.AMMO 
            ELSE 0 
         END) AS VCURK
FROM    
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.CUST CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.INVI INVI ON CUST.CODE = INVI.CSTC
WHERE 
    CUST.STAT = 'A' 
    AND (INVI.STAT = 'E' OR INVI.STAT = 'O')
GROUP BY 
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME
ORDER BY 
    CUST.CODE
```

Second query, ok:

```
SELECT  
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME,
    SUM (CASE 
            WHEN (DNVI.DTTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1))
               THEN DNVI.AMMO 
            ELSE 0 
         END) AS DCURK
FROM 
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.CUST CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.DNVI DNVI ON CUST.CODE = DNVI.CSTC
WHERE 
    CUST.STAT = 'A' 
    AND (DNVI.STAT = 'E' OR DNVI.STAT = 'O')
GROUP BY 
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME
ORDER BY 
    CUST.CODE
```

I need to get:

```
SELECT CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME, (VCURK - DCURK) as NETA
```

Anything I have tried has worked....

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 2):

Just join the two queries together as subqueries and do your math:

```
SELECT [Q1].[CODE], [Q1].[NAME], COALESCE([Q1].[VCURK], 0) - COALESCE([Q2].[DCURK], 0) AS [NETA]
FROM (
    SELECT  CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (INVI.DTTE>
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1))
            THEN INVI.AMMO ELSE 0 END) AS VCURK

    FROM    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.CUST CUST
            LEFT OUTER JOIN BAESQL_CO3.dbo.INVI INVI
            ON CUST.CODE = INVI.CSTC

    WHERE CUST.STAT = 'A' AND (INVI.STAT = 'E' OR INVI.STAT = 'O')

    GROUP BY CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME
) AS [Q1] INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME,
            SUM (CASE WHEN (DNVI.DTTE>
            DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1))
            THEN DNVI.AMMO ELSE 0 END) AS DCURK

    FROM BAESQL_CO3.dbo.CUST CUST

            LEFT OUTER JOIN BAESQL_CO3.dbo.DNVI DNVI
            ON CUST.CODE = DNVI.CSTC

    WHERE CUST.STAT = 'A' AND (DNVI.STAT = 'E' OR DNVI.STAT = 'O')

    GROUP BY CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME
) AS [Q2] ON [Q1].[CODE] = [Q2].[CODE]
ORDER BY [Q1].[CODE]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the first query. Since we use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` we can move `CASE` condition into `ON` clause, as well as this one bit of `WHERE` clause that limits the `JOIN`ed table on it's own values only. Using `AND (INVI.STAT = 'E' OR INVI.STAT = 'O')` condition on the `JOIN`ed table in `WHERE` clause effectively turns `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into `INNER JOIN`, but we can address that later:

```
SELECT  
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME,
    COALESCE(SUM(INVI.AMMO), 0) AS VCURK
FROM    
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.CUST CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.INVI INVI ON CUST.CODE = INVI.CSTC
    AND INVI.DTTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) -1, -1)
    AND (INVI.STAT = 'E' OR INVI.STAT = 'O')
WHERE 
    CUST.STAT = 'A' 
GROUP BY 
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME
ORDER BY 
    CUST.CODE
```

Please note that now we have `WHERE`, `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` all reference only the main `CUST` table.

Second query is exactly the same `JOIN`ing another table, so we can `JOIN` it into the re-factored first one:

```
SELECT
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME,
    COALESCE(SUM(INVI.AMMO), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(DNVI.AMMO), 0) AS NETA
FROM
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.CUST CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.INVI INVI ON CUST.CODE = INVI.CSTC
    AND (INVI.STAT = 'E' OR INVI.STAT = 'O')
    AND INVI.DTTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) -1, -1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.DNVI DNVI ON CUST.CODE = DNVI.CSTC
    AND (DNVI.STAT = 'E' OR DNVI.STAT = 'O')
    AND DNVI.DTTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1)
WHERE 
    CUST.STAT = 'A' 
GROUP BY 
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME
ORDER BY 
    CUST.CODE
```

Now the only difference from the original queries is that records where none of the `JOIN`ed tables have matching records are still returned in this combined query with `NETA = 0`. To replicate the original results we **can** (if actually needed) use one extra condition in `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME,
    COALESCE(SUM(INVI.AMMO), 0) - COALESCE(SUM(DNVI.AMMO), 0) AS NETA
FROM BAESQL_CO3.dbo.CUST CUST
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.INVI INVI ON CUST.CODE = INVI.CSTC
    AND (INVI.STAT = 'E' OR INVI.STAT = 'O')
    AND INVI.DTTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) -1, -1)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    BAESQL_CO3.dbo.DNVI DNVI ON CUST.CODE = DNVI.CSTC
    AND (DNVI.STAT = 'E' OR DNVI.STAT = 'O')
    AND DNVI.DTTE > DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE()) - 1, -1)
WHERE 
    CUST.STAT = 'A'
    AND (
        INVI.STAT IS NOT NULL OR INVI.STAT IS NOT NULL OR
        DNVI.STAT IS NOT NULL OR DNVI.STAT IS NOT NULL
    )
GROUP BY 
    CUST.CODE, CUST.NAME
ORDER BY 
    CUST.CODE
```

That way the query is not only shorter and more readable, but much more efficient too: no `CASE` statement, only one `GROUP BY` and date-limited `JOIN`ed tables scans.